# Как сделать такой запрос Retrofit2?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

### Задача.

---

Я хочу сделать GET запрос на сервер по следующему шаблону

http://server.com?test[{My data: String}]={My SecondData: Int}.

Пример: http://server.com?test[ifD3234oeW]=10

Можете, пожалуйта, показать как должен выглядеть подобный запрос в интерфейсе?

Какие аннотации использовать: @Query, @Path или другие?

---

Заранее спасибо за Ваши ответы!

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае только `FieldMap` поможет.
https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/FieldMap.html

Нет простой возможности имена параметров на лету менять или по шаблону.